# Real-time tracking of web Geolocation

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, geolocation, google-chrome-devtools

I'm writing a web app that tracks user location. I wanted to test in a browser if changing geolocation will update UI in real-time. Something like when you use google map and physically move the map is updated accordingly.

I came across Chrome geolocation sensor but it does not update the location in real-time. I need to refresh the whole page to get location changed

Does anyone have any idea how can I do it in real-time?

I'm using google-maps-react

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize a JS timer to do this for you. Using `setInterval`, just add the function to check for a user's GPS location.

```
setInterval(
    function(){ 
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            this.setState({pos: position.coords});
        }); 
    },
3000);
```

Afterwards, you can update the map in real time as the state changes by using `this.state.pos.latitude` and `this.state.pos.latitude`. This updates the user's location every 3 seconds, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out!
I used `react-geolocated` and set `watchPosition` to `true`. Which enables live tracking and whenever I change  Chrome geolocation sensor it updates :-)